# Core OpenGL context when Compatibility requested?

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

Here's my code:

```
// Display.cpp

#include <memory>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <GL/glew.h>

namespace Display
{
    constexpr static int WIDTH  = 1280; constexpr static int HEIGHT = 720;

    std::unique_ptr<sf::RenderWindow> window;
    void init() {
        sf::ContextSettings settings;
        settings.depthBits = 24;
        settings.majorVersion = 3;
        settings.minorVersion = 3; // OpenGL 3.3
        settings.attributeFlags = sf::ContextSettings::Default;

        window = std::make_unique<sf::RenderWindow>(sf::VideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT),
                                                    "Fcku",
                                                    sf::Style::Close,
                                                    settings);
        glewInit();
        glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }

    void close() {
        window->close();     
    }

    void clear() {
        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    void update() {
        window->display();
    }

    void checkForClose() {
        sf::Event e;
        while (window->pollEvent(e))
            if (e.type == sf::Event::Closed) close();
    }

    bool isOpen() {
        return window->isOpen();
    }

} // namespace Display

int main()
{
    Display::init();

    while (Display::isOpen()) {
        Display::clear();
        Display::update();

        Display::checkForClose();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I compile the above files like so:

```
g++ Display.cpp -Wall -O2 --std=c++14 -fexceptions -o test.o -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-audio -lsfml-network -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW -DGLEW_STATIC
```

(haven't gotten around to writing a makefile yet)

This produces a binary named `test` but when I run it I get the following warning:

```
Warning: The created OpenGL context does not fully meet the settings that were requested
Requested: version = 4.1 ; depth bits = 24 ; stencil bits = 0 ; AA level = 0 ; core = false ; debug = false ; sRGB = false
Created: version = 3.3 ; depth bits = 24 ; stencil bits = 0 ; AA level = 0 ; core = true ; debug = false ; sRGB = false
```

This does create a black window (as expected) but I suspect that once I start using the Drawing functions in `SFML/Graphics.hpp` it'll segfault, because that happened when I tried to compile an example file (it printed the same error as well).

When I create my `sf::ContextSettings` I set it's `attributeFlags` to `sf::ContextSettings::Default` so from my understanding it should create a compatibility context (since SFML uses some legacy code this is a must).

P.S. If it matters, I'm on Void Linux and I installed the most up-to-date versions of everything that I used here from the repos

Comment: How about you show us your *actual* source code?

Comment: Code goes *in* the question. *Not* behind off-site links. And it should be posted as *text* and be a [mcve].

Comment: We don't you to post the entire code, just the initialization part obviosuly.

Comment: There you go guys, I think this is good enough

Comment: What display driver/OpenGL implementation are you using? If you use Mesa, it only supports Core Profile.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine [these](http://i.imgur.com/nlCeTzX.png) are all of my installed packages that contain 'OpenGL' in their name, so I think that I do use Mesa. Do I have any alternatives? I can already think of a few. One option would be installing AMD's OpenGL, and another option would be remote-(cross?)-compiling on a Windows machine (if that's even possible).

Comment: Ok, so Void's repos have the AMD libs but the actual catalyst drivers are obsolete and don't support my version of xorg (only an older version), so I'm screwed. I guess I'll look at SFML alternatives. One such alternative is SDL, and another is Raylib (although Raylib does a lot for you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, seems like the solution was to use OpenGL 3.0 instead of 3.3, which does support the compatibility profile. But now I can't use GLSL 3.30 and it's a big mess, so I'll try SDL2, GLFW and Raylib.